# Múltiplos INNER JOINS com DAPPER

Tags: c#, dapper

Estou tentando realizar múltiplos `INNER JOIN` no `Dapper` com estas classes:

```
public class EventoConfiguracao
{
    public EventoConfiguracao()
    {
        //CdEventoConfiguracao = Guid.NewGuid();
     Menus = new List<Menu>();
        MenuLaterais  =new List<MenuLateral>();
        Categorias =new List<Categoria>();
        Produtos=new List<Produto>();
       CupomDescontos =new List<CupomDesconto>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CdEvento { get; set; }
    public virtual Evento Evento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CupomDesconto> CupomDescontos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuLateral> MenuLaterais { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Menu
{

    public Menu()
    {
        SubMenus = new List<Menu>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string RotaUrl { get; set; }
    public int? MenuTipoId { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuTipo MenuTipo { get; set; }
    public int? MenuParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu MenuParente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> SubMenus { get; set; }
    public int EventoConfiguracaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventoConfiguracao EventoConfiguracao { get; set; }
    public bool IsCarrousel { get; set; }
    public bool IsPainel { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
public class Produto()
{
    public Produto()
    {
        PedidoDetalhes = new List<PedidoDetalhe>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NrProduto { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Qtd { get; set; }
    public int? EventoConfiguracaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventoConfiguracao EventoConfiguracao { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Categoria
{
    public Categoria()
    {
        Produtos = new List<Produto>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public int? EventoConfiguracaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventoConfiguracao EventoConfiguracao { get; set; }
}
```

Ao realizar o `INNER JOIN` com 2 ou mais tabelas no `Dapper`, está aparecendo esta mensagem de error:

> `Additional information: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id`

ao executar o código abaixo:

```
public IEnumerable<EventoConfiguracao> ObterProdutoPorCategoria(string categoria, int clienteId, int cdEvento)
{
        var cn = Db.Database.Connection;
        var sql = @"SELECT e.[Id] as 'EventoID', e.[Nome], p.Id as 'ProdId', p.Nome FROM EventoConfiguracao e " +
                  "INNER JOIN Categoria c " +
                  "ON  e.Id = c.[EventoConfiguracaoId] " +
                  "INNER JOIN Produto p " +
                  "ON p.CategoriaId = c.Id " +
                  "LEFT JOIN Menu m  " +
                  "ON e.Id  = m.EventoConfiguracaoId " +
                  "where c.Descricao = @scategoria AND e.CdEvento = @scdEvento " +
                "GROUP BY e.[Id], e.[Nome], p.Id, p.Nome ";

        Debug.WriteLine(sql);
        var eventoConfiguracao = new List<EventoConfiguracao>();
        cn.Query<EventoConfiguracao, Produto, Categoria,Menu, EventoConfiguracao>(sql,
            (e, p,c,m) =>
            {
                eventoConfiguracao.Add(e);
                if (e != null)
                {
                    eventoConfiguracao[0].Categorias.Add(c);
                    eventoConfiguracao[0].Produtos.Add(p);
                    eventoConfiguracao[0].Menus.Add(m);
                }

                return eventoConfiguracao.FirstOrDefault();
            }, new { scategoria =categoria,  scdEvento = cdEvento }, ***splitOn: "EventoID,ProdId,Id,m.Id");***

        return eventoConfiguracao;
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

- 1º Nessa linha de código "cn.Query" eu informei 3 classes, é necessário também incluir os campos das outras (Menu e Categoria) junto no select?
- 2º O SplitOn sempre é necessário informar chave primária?
- 3º A ordem informada nos parâmetros do DAPPER
  `**cn.Query<EventoConfiguracao, Produto, Categoria,Menu, EventoConfiguracao> sql,                (e, p,c,m) =>**` o SplitON tem que seguir a mesma sequência de Keys das tabelas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1º Nessa linha de código "cn.Query" eu informei 3 classes, é necessário também incluir os campos das outras (Menu e Categoria) junto no select?

Necessário não, mas, quanto mais completa uma *query*, melhor a qualidade das informações.

> 2º O SplitOn sempre é necessário informar chave primária?

Não. `splitOn` é um parâmetro que serve apenas para o Dapper saber onde termina os campos de uma classe e onde começa os campos de outra classe. Não necessariamente precisa ser chave primária.

> 3º A ordem informada nos parâmetros do DAPPER
>   `cn.Query<EventoConfiguracao, Produto, Categoria,Menu, EventoConfiguracao> sql, (e, p,c,m) =>` o SplitON tem que seguir a mesma sequência de Keys das tabelas?

A ordem dos campos das tabelas no SQL precisa seguir a ordem dos campos na declaração da *query*. Ou seja, se a definição está como:

```
cn.Query<EventoConfiguracao, Produto, Categoria, Menu, EventoConfiguracao>(...
```

A ordem dos campos precisa ser:

1. `EventoConfiguracao`;
2. `Produto`;
3. `Categoria`;
4. `Menu`.

Adicionalmente, sim, pode-se dizer que o `splitOn` precisa seguir esta mesma ordem. Lembrando que `splitOn` não trabalha necessariamente com chaves, mas com qualquer campo.

Possivelmente isto não irá funcionar:

```
splitOn: "EventoID,ProdId,Id,m.Id"
```

Não há `Id` ou `m.Id` especificadas entre as colunas. Eu faria algo assim:

```
var sql = @"SELECT e.[Id] as 'EventoID', e.[Nome], p.Id as 'ProdId', p.Nome, c.Id as CatId, c.Descricao, m.Id as MenuId, m.Nome " +
              "FROM EventoConfiguracao e " +
              "INNER JOIN Categoria c " +
              "ON  e.Id = c.[EventoConfiguracaoId] " +
              "INNER JOIN Produto p " +
              "ON p.CategoriaId = c.Id " +
              "LEFT JOIN Menu m  " +
              "ON e.Id  = m.EventoConfiguracaoId " +
              "where c.Descricao = @scategoria AND e.CdEvento = @scdEvento ";
```

E o `splitOn`:

```
splitOn: "EventoID,ProdId,CatId,MenuId"
```

Note que é importante que as colunas de ID tenham nomes únicos, para que o Dapper não se atrapalhe na hora de fazer o *split* corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado Morrison, sempre ajudando ai e esclarecendo bem. Vou tentar aqui.