# Problemas com o Inner Join no Dapper

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Estou com o seguinte problema, quando efetuo um ***inner join*** em ***3*** tabelas o ***Dapper*** não me traz todas as colunas das 3 tabelas e sim só a da tabela pai do meu ***inner join*** ( ou seja a primeira tabela na query ).

***Minhas classes***

```
public class ItemQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int Questao_Id { get; set; }    
    public int Resposta_Id { get; set; }    
}    

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Questao { get; set; }    
}  

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Resposta { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
    conn.Open();
    Dictionary<string, string> quest = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    return conn
        .Query<ItemQuestion, Question, Answer, ItemQuestion>
            (@"SELECT ITQ.*, Q.*, AWS.* FROM ITEM_QUESTION AS ITQ 
                INNER JOIN QUESTION AS Q ON Q.Id = ITQ.Questao_Id 
                INNER JOIN ANSWER AS AWS ON AWS.Id = ITQ.Resposta_Id",
                (itq, q, a) =>
                {
                    itq.Questao_Id = q.Id;
                    itq.Resposta_Id = a.Id;
                    return itq;

            }).ToList();                         
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Múltiplos INNER JOINS com DAPPER](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178917/m%c3%baltiplos-inner-joins-com-dapper)

Comment: Outro exemplo: http://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping

Comment: Qual é a cardinalidade das três tabelas?

Comment: @gato A tabla `QUESTION` é de `1:1` para a tabela `ITEM_QUESTION`,  assim com a tabela `ANSWER`, já a table `ITEM_QUESTION` é de `n:n`.

Comment: @William uma questão tem apenas um `item` e uma resposta pode ter vários `item`?

Comment: @gato Não uma item pode ter varias resposta e varias perguntas.